# Assembly - Heap alignment - x86 intel

Tags: assembly, malloc, alignment, heap-memory, memory-alignment

I think I understood stack alignment which is 4-bytes, for example if I add one only char, his address will be at the right of the 4 bytes (a little before if there are other 1 or 2 bytes variables)

Still I can't understand the alignment in the heap, I thought there was 4-bytes or 8 bytes alignment but here's the thing, when I allocate 100 then 20 bytes, there are 4 bytes between the end of the first one and the beginning of the second, so I guessed that the heap would use 8bytes alignment.

By consecutivly allocating 1 4 7 8 9 14 16 17 bytes I noticed that 1, 4, 7, 8, 9 take 16 bytes each and 14 16 17 take 24 bytes, why so ?

I am using C/C++ and using malloc to allocate (same thing with new).

Thank you.

Comment: Might depend on *how* you are allocating these things, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Sorry, Im using C/C++ and I allocate them with a malloc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, the `malloc` function is documented to return memory aligned on a 8-byte boundary for 32-bit applications, and on a 16-byte boundary for 64-bit applications. On Linux, it only said that it returns "*memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable*", but it probably is also 8 and 16.

On top of that, `malloc` needs to reserve additional memory to store the tracking data necessary to manage the heap. This means that when you ask for N bytes, `malloc` will actually use N+X bytes, with X being constant and dependent on the implementation.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I'm using Linux, it is still weird that allocation 1 bytes need 16 bytes (15 extra bytes) while allocation 100 needs 104 bytes. Does this extra bytes to manage heap have a name so I can do some research ? Or do you have any documentation page ?

Comment: @x4rkz About 1 byte needing 16, the allocation mechanism is probably not that simple. Maybe allocating 104 or 105 bytes will use 112 ? If it's the case, maybe the additional data needs some kind of alignment too. About the additional data itself, I don't know exactly how it works, but I think it's a pointer to some malloc state structure. I'm not sure it has a special name.

Comment: Windows x64 and x86-64 System V ABIs both have `alignof(max_align_t) = 16` (https://godbolt.org/z/4dKhfeqhn), so you're guaranteed that much alignment from malloc (at least for allocations of at least 16 bytes; in theory a smaller allocation could be less aligned because it couldn't hold a 16-byte type anyway).  But yes, in 32-bit code, malloc may only give you 8 byte alignment, or in theory only 4 if there aren't any types with `alignof(T) == 8`.  (Most modern 32-bit x86 implementations choose to give 8 for performance, in case it's used for a `double` or something.)

Answer (score 3):

Alignment is just about the location of the start of something: that its address will be a multiple of A.  Where the memory manager puts those allocations, and why, is totally its business, and may be (in part) dependent on other things going on in the computer outside of your program.  This means that you can't determine the "size" of a previous allocation by the location of the "next" one (while it may be next to your program, it may not be next to the memory manager); in fact, it is possible for the "next" allocation to have a *smaller* address (if, for example, lower memory has been freed in the interim).